# Как сменить тему в Elementary OS?

Tags: linux, elementary-os

А есть приложение по типу "Темы" с linux mint, только для elementary?
Спасибо)

Comment: Зачем? По-моему, если из Elementary убрать тему, то получится просто кривая Ubuntu. Этот дистрибутив кроме как темой больше ничем и не выделяется. Все приложения, которые пилят исключительно под него, как раз заточены под эту тему.

Comment: Я оставил вам ответ, дайте знать, если он вам помог (галочкой). В противном случае попытаюсь найти другое решение вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел утилиту Tweaks. Tweaks - это необходимые настройки для оформления операционной системы: расположение кнопок, управления окон, выбор темы оформления, шрифты, анимация, тени и многое другое. 
Установить можно с помощью `sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks`.

Если что-то не получается - можете спросить, попробую помочь.